# Do punctuation marks take on the formatting of the preceding word?

Tags: punctuation

If the last word of a sententece is in boldface, should the question mark be bolded as well?

Which example is correct (see below)?

*Example 1: **How much** did your hip, leg or foot **hurt?***

*Example 2: **How much** did your hip, leg or foot **hurt**?*

What about a different punctuation mark, like a colon, a comma or a period (see below)?

*Example 3: **Explain:** are you currently sick?*

*Example 4: **Explain**: are you currently sick?*

*Example 5: If your hip **hurts,** please indicate the intensity of the **pain.***

*Example 6: If your hip **hurts**, please indicate the intensity of the **pain**.*

Thank you for your input!

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that this is difficult because we have no idea why you are switching typeface in the middle of the sentence. An italicized title, for example, would only have italicized punctuation if it was part of the title.

Hence:

> I am reading *Antifragile: Things That Gain from Disorder*, and it's robust.

not

> I am reading *Antifragile*: *Things That Gain from Disorder,* and it's robust.

The rule in this case is that if the item being set off by the distinctive typeface (in this case a book title) would include the punctuation if it was on its own (separate from the sentence) then that punctuation should be in the distinctive typeface. If, on the other hand, the punctuation belongs to the sentence that frames the object then it would not be in the distinctive typeface.

Because you are merely emphasizing individual words with boldface, we would say that the word is what's different than the rest of the sentence. The word should be bold and the punctuation surrounding it should be the same as the rest of the sentence.

Comment: That's about it...except in special circumstances when your emphasis typeface and size is dramatically different to body copy. A body copy (small font size) ending question mark would look rather weird next to a ending emphasis word that is very big and bold. Compromises have to be made for visual effect, as always.

Comment: Thanks for the input! The switch in the typeface is for emphasis (I suspect, as I'm not the author of the text but merely a translator). Therefore, I believe in this case the punctuation surrounding the word should be consistent with the rest of the sentence. I was just wondering what the rule of thumb was...